# How do I update datetime field using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I have this function wherein I can update my input fields, I have a fetch.php that fetches data from my sql.

So this is my input fields --> [Sample Pic - Input Fields][1]
Then when I click update it returns this --> [Sample Pic - Updating Input Fields][2]

My problem is whenever I update it returns all of the data in the fields except the date and time? How can I fix this?

Below are my codes. TYVM.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="date_submitted" id="date_submitted" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Submitted" style="width: 120%;" />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        addDocu();

        function addDocu() {
            var action = "select";
            $.ajax({
                url: success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    addDocu();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("All Fields are Required");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#action').text("Save");
                $('#docu_id').val(id);
                $('#code').val(data.code);
                $('#doc_kind').val(data.doc_kind);
                $('#date_submitted').val(data.date_submitted);
                $('#remarks').val(data.remarks);

            }
        })
        "select.php",
        method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: action
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#code').val('');
                $('#doc_kind').val('');
                $('#date_submitted').value('');
                $('#remarks').val('');
                $('#action').text("Add");
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
    });
    }
    $('#action').click(function() {
        var docCode = $('#code').val();
        var docKind = $('#doc_kind').val();
        var dateSubmitted = $('#date_submitted').val();
        var docRemarks = $('#remarks').val();
        var id = $('#docu_id').val();
        var action = $('#action').text();
        if (docCode != '' && docKind != '' && dateSubmitted != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    docCode: docCode,
                    docKind: docKind,
                    dateSubmitted: dateSubmitted,
                    docRemarks: docRemarks,
                    id: id,
                    action: action
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    addDocu();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("All Fields are Required");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#action').text("Save");
                $('#docu_id').val(id);
                $('#code').val(data.code);
                $('#doc_kind').val(data.doc_kind);
                $('#date_submitted').val(data.date_submitted);
                $('#remarks').val(data.remarks);

            }
        })
    });
</script>

if(isset($_POST["id"]))  
{
    $output = array();  
    $procedure = "  
    CREATE PROCEDURE whereDocu(IN docu_id int(11))  
    BEGIN   
    SELECT * FROM officesectb WHERE id = docu_id;  
    END;   
    "; 

function convert ($rem) {
$rem = trim($rem);
return preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $rem);
}
    if(mysqli_query($connect, "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS whereDocu"))  
    {  
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $procedure))  
        {
            $query = "CALL whereDocu(".$_POST["id"].")";  
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {
                $rem = $row["remarks"];

                  $output['code'] = $row["code"];  
                $output['doc_kind'] = $row["doc_kind"];  
                $output['date_submitted'] = $row['date_submitted']; 
                $output['remarks'] = convert($rem);
            }  

            echo json_encode($output);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: To much code. Make it more concrete.

Comment: let us know what type of `date_submited` field in your db, plis

Comment: is date_submitted the right name for your DB field? Is it the right name for your HTML element? Is there even definitely data in the DB in that field? We don't know at what stage the data is going missing.

Comment: P.S. Why are you dropping and re-creating the stored procedure on every request? That's crazy!

Comment: Can't see any `<?php>` tag in there...  Do a `var_dump($row)` in your while, does it have your date and time values?